# Python pandas sort alphanumeric

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

Im trying to sort a txt file in python containing some information about movies (taken from https://datasets.imdbws.com/). My small sample I've been working on is this:

```
titleId ordering    title   region  language    types   attributes  isOriginalTitle
tt1037178   1   Women's Studies US  \N  \N  \N  0
tt10371782  1   Episodio #1.67  IT  it  \N  \N  0
tt10371782  2   एपिसोड #1.67    IN  hi  \N  \N  0
tt10371782  3   エピソード #1.67 JP  ja  \N  \N  0
tt10371790  4   एपिसोड #1.70    IN  hi  \N  \N  0
tt10371790  5   エピソード #1.70 JP  ja  \N  \N  0
tt10371790  6   Épisode #1.70   FR  fr  \N  \N  0
tt10371790  7   Folge #1.70 DE  de  \N  \N  0
tt1037179   1   Wood Simps  US  \N  \N  \N  0
```

I'm using the following code to sort:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('title.akas_test_input.txt', sep='\t', low_memory=False)
a=df.sort_values("titleId", ascending=True)
a.to_csv("title.akas_test_output.txt", sep='\t', index=None)
```

and the output is:

```
titleId ordering    title   region  language    types   attributes  isOriginalTitle
tt1037178   1   Women's Studies US  \N  \N  \N  0
tt10371782  1   Episodio #1.67  IT  it  \N  \N  0
tt10371782  2   एपिसोड #1.67    IN  hi  \N  \N  0
tt10371782  3   エピソード #1.67 JP  ja  \N  \N  0
tt1037179   1   Wood Simps  US  \N  \N  \N  0
tt10371790  4   एपिसोड #1.70    IN  hi  \N  \N  0
tt10371790  5   エピソード #1.70 JP  ja  \N  \N  0
tt10371790  6   Épisode #1.70   FR  fr  \N  \N  0
tt10371790  7   Folge #1.70 DE  de  \N  \N  0
```

while my expected output would be this:

```
titleId ordering    title   region  language    types   attributes  isOriginalTitle
tt1037178   1   Women's Studies US  \N  \N  \N  0
tt1037179   1   Wood Simps  US  \N  \N  \N  0
tt10371782  1   Episodio #1.67  IT  it  \N  \N  0
tt10371782  2   एपिसोड #1.67    IN  hi  \N  \N  0
tt10371782  3   エピソード #1.67 JP  ja  \N  \N  0
tt10371790  4   एपिसोड #1.70    IN  hi  \N  \N  0
tt10371790  5   エピソード #1.70 JP  ja  \N  \N  0
tt10371790  6   Épisode #1.70   FR  fr  \N  \N  0
tt10371790  7   Folge #1.70 DE  de  \N  \N  0
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your column has string type. Sorting that type of column will return [Lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). For your purposes I would extract part with number firstly and sort by it afterwards. For example:

```
df['titleId_number']=df['titleId'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split('tt')[1]))
df.sort_values('titleId_number')
```

Comment: Really appreciate it! There is an extra column at the end though, called titleId_number. How can I remove that? EDIT: I'll just simply drop the last column

Answer (score 0):

```
df['titleId_number']=df['titleId'].str.split('tt')[1].astype(int)
```

The lambda function is not required.